# getting two values using comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to yield the following using comprehension, I have tried getting both values a,b etc.. but the only way I know is through indexing and when I do that I get string index out of range.

```
path = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

--

```
a, b
b, c
c, d
d, e
```

Comment: What should it return for an empty list `[]`? For a list of len 1 `[x]`?

Comment: there won't be an empty list.

Comment: which is the most efficient over very large paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip` here:

```
>>> lis =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for x,y in zip(lis,lis[1:]):
...     print x,y
...     
a b
b c
c d
d e
```

Comment: +1, You got there before me, but I'll leave my answer up, as there are a few cases where the iterator approach is a little better (where the original data is a list, they are pretty much equivalent).

Answer (score 4):

[`itertools` pairwise recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) works on any iterable

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

path = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for x, y in pairwise(path):
    print x, y


a b
b c
c d
d e
>>> list(pairwise(path))
[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e')]
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this is not through a list comprehension, but [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
advanced = iter(path)
next(advanced, None)
for item, next_item in zip(path, advanced):
    ...
```

We produce an iterator over the values, advance it by one so we start with the second value, then loop through the original list and the advanced one at the same time using `zip()`.

Comment: Slightly more readable IMHO would be: `for item, next_item in zip(path, islice(path, 1, None))` ... It's more explicit than `iter` and then `next`'ing it

Comment: @JonClements If you are going to import `itertools`, you might as well just use the pairwise solution. I can't say I think using `islice` is that different, but it's perfectly valid.

Comment: +1 But you should do `next(advanced, None)`, this is nicer than my solution for this case